# Can a iOS8 Custom Keyboard know what app it is in?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8

Can a iOS8 Custom Keyboard know what app it is writing to?  I would like for my Custom Keyboard to act differently if it is in Safari than in Mail, Photos, Contacts etc.  I have tried

```
NSString *appName = [NSString stringWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"]];
```

and

```
NSString *home_folder = NSHomeDirectory() ;
```

but those just point to the enclosing app, which of course never changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to check what app your keyboard is entering text into. There's no mention of it on either the documentation for [UIInputViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIInputViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIInputViewController/requestSupplementaryLexiconWithCompletion:), nor the more general documentation for [Keyboard Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW1).

Additionally, this would be quite confusing to a user. As a user myself, I rely on the keyboard being the same in each app. Otherwise, it's orders of magnitude harder for me to learn to type effortlessly.

Comment: Good point, but I'm looking to do something close to when the System keyboard Return key changes its title based upon the returnKeyType property of a UITextField.

Comment: @DKLA Good idea! That wouldn't be as disorienting to the user. I still don't believe there's any way to do it.

Comment: The keyboard has access to the container's app's user defaults with app groups enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's default keyboard's appearance is **independent** of the app it runs in. The keyboard's appearance is controlled by the object the keyboard is currently responding too. What this means is that you can't force the keyboard to go into a specific state (only the `UITextfield` / `UITextView` can).

However you can definitely respond accordingly by working with various traits such as `UIReturnKeyType`.

## UIReturnKeyType

You can do the following to specify different keyboard customizations based on the return key type (P.S. The example below assumes that your return key button is called `returnButton`):

```
if (UIReturnKeyType == UIReturnKeyDone) {
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

else if (UIReturnKeyType == UIReturnKeyGo) {
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Go" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Go" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

else if (UIReturnKeyType == UIReturnKeyJoin) {
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Join" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Join" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

else if (UIReturnKeyType == UIReturnKeyNext) {
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

else if (UIReturnKeyType == UIReturnKeySend) {
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Send" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Send" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

else if (UIReturnKeyType == UIReturnKeyYahoo) {
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Yahoo!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Yahoo!" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

else if (UIReturnKeyType == UIReturnKeySearch) {
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Search" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Search" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

else if (UIReturnKeyType == UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall) {
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Emergency" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Emergency" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

else if (UIReturnKeyType == UIReturnKeyRoute) {       
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Route" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Route" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

else if (UIReturnKeyType == UIReturnKeyGoogle) {
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Google" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Google" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

else {
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Return" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Return" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

## UIKeyboardAppearance

Keep in mind there's other things you can respond to as well, such as whether the UITextField / UITextView prefers a light or dark keyboard.

```
if (UIKeyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearanceDark) {
    //Customize your keyboard's dark mode
} else {
    //Customize your keyboard's light mode
}
```

For more information, I recommend reading up on [UITextInputTraits](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html). I'm happy you're actually considering handling all this! Most third party keyboards lack some of the most basic features, which is unfortunate.